# How to set validation using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

when I am open dialog box in that one small register page.
on register button click event i call Ajax function submit data.
so How to set Require validation
Below code is in Dialog Box

input field
in last 
save

On Anchor tag id saveData Call Ajax and save data...

Answer (score 0):

Try writing validation code or use [**jQuery validation plugin**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

well [Mobilevikings](https://mobilevikings.com/nl/) has a nice validation system using JQuery, you should check that out :)

edit: you should look through their source-code for the **form-validation.js** file :)